# Multiple Digital Signatures in Oracle BI Publisher Report PDF output

Tags: xml, oracle, report, digital-signature, bi-publisher

Including multiple digital signatures in BI Publisher report pdf output.

Oracle provides mechanism to have just 1 digital signature.

Answer (score 0):

Digital Signature is to prove 2 things:

1. The document is coming from the person who is claiming to be author of the document.
2. Document has not been changed after it is digitally signed.

Thus digital signature is applied to whole document content irrespective of number of pages.  If you want to apply digital signature of multiple approves, that is possible in pdf.  If you are looking to put same digital signature on each page of document, as required by people who wants to print digitally signed pdf and wants digital signature stamp to appear on each printed page, this is nuisance as far as digitally signed document is concerned..!!!

Comment: If you want to apply digital signature of multiple approves, that is possible in pdf. I wan't to know how this can be done in BI Publisher.

Comment: Was there any progress for this requirement. You may refer to [Signer.Digital](https://signer.digital/) solution provided by My Company